# select name of a person with the most grandchildren

Tags: sql, database, select, hierarchical-data

I have a simple table with persons, but there is a additional
field witch holds information (person id) who is a father/mother
of that person, so the 2 dimensional table can hold a familly tree

the table is

```
id first_name  last_name salary spouse_id father_id mother_id sex
100 Steven King 26400 101 (null) (null) m  
101 Neena Kochhar 18700 100 (null) (null) f  
102 Lex De Haan 18700 106 100 101 m  
103 Alexander Hunold 9900 (null) 100 101 m  
104 Bruce Ernst 6600 (null) 102 106 m  
105 David Austin 5280 (null) 102 106 m  
106 Valli Pataballa 5280 102 (null) (null) f  
107 Diana Lorentz 4620 (null) (null) (null) f  
108 Nancy Greenberg 13200 109 (null) (null) f  
109 Daniel Faviet 9900 108 115 116 m  
110 John Chen 9020 (null) 109 108 m  
111 Ismael Sciarra 8470 (null) 109 108 m  
112 Jose Manuel Urman 8580 (null) 109 108 m  
113 Luis Popp 7590 (null) 109 108 m  
114 Den Raphaely 12100 (null) 109 108 m  
115 Alexander Khoo 3410 116 (null) (null) m  
116 Shelli Baida 3190 115 (null) (null) f
```

**The task is to select person name which has biggest number of grandchildren**

All I managed to do is:

```
select 
e1.first_name, e1.last_name
--,max (e3.first_name)
,count(e3.first_name) grandchilds
from empnew e1
inner join
empnew e2
on (e1.id = e2.father_id)
inner join
empnew e3
on (e2.id = e3.father_id)
group by e1.first_name, e1.last_name
```

and the result is

```
first_name last_name grandchilds
Steven King 2
Alexander Khoo 5
```

please help :)
ps: I would like to get **RDBMS independent answer if it is possible**

Comment: You're forgetting mothers. (Which, since you have no single parents, may not be too much of a concern to you).

Comment: If this is homework please tag it as such.

Comment: You can forget about Mothers (mother_id) - it will be easier and I can do it without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I did it, please take a look at my solution and comment it

```
SELECT 
e1.first_name
, e1.last_name
, count(e3.first_name) AS grandchilds
FROM empnew e1
INNER JOIN
empnew e2
ON (e1.id = e2.father_id)
INNER JOIN
empnew e3
ON (e2.id = e3.father_id)
GROUP BY e1.first_name, e1.last_name
HAVING COUNT(e3.first_name)
=
(SELECT MAX (grandchilds) FROM
(
SELECT 
e1.first_name
, COUNT(e3.first_name) AS grandchilds
FROM empnew e1
INNER JOIN
empnew e2
ON (e1.id = e2.father_id)
INNER JOIN
empnew e3
ON (e2.id = e3.father_id)
GROUP BY e1.first_name
) table_1);
```

*edit: I fixed it up as 'onedaywhen' said*

Comment: Doesn't work on SQL Server (one of the most used SQL products) but can be fixed by giving your derived table a correlation name e.g. replace `))` with `) AS DT1 )`.

Comment: ...to be honest, if you want a SQL-product-independent answer, why aren't you writing SQL compliant with the SQL-92 Standard: upper case keywords (`SELECT` rather than `select`), using the `AS` keyword for correlation names (`empnew AS e1` rather than `empnew e1` and `COUNT(e3.first_name) AS grandchilds` rather than `count(e3.first_name) grandchilds`), ending statements with a semicolon `;`.

Comment: to be honset I didn't know that! :)

Comment: fwiw, SQL keywords are not required to be upper case.  http://kb.askmonty.org/en/sql-language-elements

Answer (score 0):

The following is an ANSI solution except for the `strpos` function (which is PostgreSQL specific). But it shouldn't be hard to find the correct function that finds a substring in another string.

```
with recursive person_tree as (
   select id, first_name, last_name, cast(id as varchar)||'/' as id_path, id as root_id
   from persons
   where father_id is null

   union all

   select c.id, c.first_name, c.last_name, id_path || cast(c.id as varchar)||'/', null
   from persons c 
     join person_tree p on c.father_id = p.id
),
group_flags as (
  select id_path, 
         id,
         first_name,
         last_name,
         substring(id_path, 0, strpos(id_path, '/')) as root_id
  from person_tree
)
select root_id, count(*) 
from group_flags
group by root_id
having count(*) = (select max(children_count)
                   from (select root_id,
                                count(*) as children_count
                         from group_flags
                         group by root_id
                   ) t)
```

I tested this with PostgreSQL, but it should also work on Firebird, SQL Server, DB2, Oracle 11gR2 and Teradata. Not all of them accept the (according to the standard) mandatory keyword `recursive`, so you might need to remove that depending on the target DBMS.

SQL Server breaks the standard by not using `||` for string concatenation. You must use `+` instead.

**Edit**:

Just noticed that it will count *all* children not only the grandchildren, so it's not 100% what you want.